# Converting Objective-C bytes code to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm having trouble converting my Objective-C code to Swift 2.

This is my Objective-C code:

```
NSString* wifiname = wifiName;
NSData *wifinames = [wifiname dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSUInteger wifinamelength = [wifinames length];
Byte wifiNamelengths[1] = {wifinamelength};
```

I converted it to the following, but am receiving a couple of errors:

```
var wifiname: String = wifiName
var wifinames: NSData = wifiname.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

var wifinamelength: Int = wifinames.length
var wifiNamelengths[1] : UInt8 = {wifinamelength}
```

Here are the errors:
[image]

Could anybody help me figure out why this is happening please?

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems with that line of code.

This is probably what you want:

```
var wifiNamelengths: [UInt8] = [UInt8(wifinamelength)]
```

Note the syntax for arrays is quite different to that in your code. Also, casting is needed.

Answer (score 2):

The errors are due to incorrect syntax for using an array.

You would also need to explicitly type-cast the value of length to a `UInt8` since Swift 2 does not allow automatic type-casting.

The correct syntax would be something like:

```
var wifiNamelengths: [UInt8] = [ UInt8(wifinames.length) ]
```

Unless there's a specific reason to store the value as a UInt8, this can be simplified by using type-inference and storing the values as an array of `Int`:

```
var wifiNamelengths = [ wifinames.length ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The array declaration and initialisation syntax is wrong, you are using Objective C/C style syntax there.

You should change that to:

```
var wifiNamelengths : [UInt8] = [UInt8(wifinamelength)]
```

For fixing the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171544/converting-objective-c-bytes-code-to-swift/38171647?noredirect=1#comment63770474_38171647) mentioned by @MartinR

```
var wifiNamelengths : [UInt8] = [UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: wifinamelength)]
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171544/converting-objective-c-bytes-code-to-swift/38171647?noredirect=1#comment63770869_38171647): [UInt8 Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_UInt8_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structctr/UInt8/s:FVs5UInt8cFT20truncatingBitPatternSi_S_)

Comment: Just note that this will crash if wifinamelength > 255 (applies to the other answers as well).

Comment: @MartinR His original Obj-C code probably won't work as expected as well in that case. In fact, crashing might be a better choice than what happened before. :)

Comment: @Eiko: That may be. I just wanted to mention that Swift does not implicitly truncate (as C does).

Comment: @MartinR: You are correct. Is there anyway we can avoid that crash ? Can add a value check before converting to UInt8, but is there any native methods available to handle this issue ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_UInt8_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structctr/UInt8/s:FVs5UInt8cFT20truncatingBitPatternSi_S_ would behave as the Objective-C code.

Comment: @MartinR: Thank you verymuch for the precious information. I've updated my answer

Comment: Keep in mind that this is rarely ever what you want. If wifinamelength is 256, you get 0 now... for 257 you get 1 etc. I don't think this will ever make sense, and it buries this design bug and makes it even harder to track down. Looking in a crash report you will see the problem within 5 seconds, getting a user report of some not-working network will probably cost you days, *if* you can ever track it down at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below.Convert objective-c to Swift.

```
var wifiname: String = wifiName

var wifinames: NSData = wifiname.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

var wifinamelength: Int = wifinames.characters.count

var wifiNamelengths:[Byte] = [wifinamelength]
```